# movedown method not saving new position - cakephp tree

Tags: php, cakephp, tree

I am experiencing a problem that has popped up recently and is causing quite a bit of trouble for our system.

The app we have relies on using the movedown method to organize content, but as of late it has stopped working and began to generate the following warning:

```
Warning (2): array_values() [<a href='function.array-values'>function.array-values</a>]: The argument should be an array in [/usr/local/home/cake/cake_0_2_9/cake/libs/model/behaviors/tree.php, line 459]
```

The line being referenced:

```
list($node) = array_values($Model->find('first', array(
   'conditions' => array($scope, $Model->escapeField() => $id),
   'fields' => array($Model->primaryKey, $left, $right, $parent), 'recursive' => $recursive
  )));
```

The line calling the method:

```
$this->movedown($id,abs((int)$position));
```

I have exhausted every idea I could come up with. Has anyone else crossed this issue before?

Any help, or pointing in a direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: What are the data types and example values for your variables?  What is the output when you print_r on your Model::find call, without the assignment or the array_values call?

Answer (score 1):

Simplify your problem

```
Configure::write('debug', 1); // <- turn on debug mode (if not set earlier)

$fields = array($Model->primaryKey, $left, $right, $parent), 'recursive' => $recursive));
$conditions = array($scope, $Model->escapeField() => $id);
$results = $Model->find('first', array(
   'conditions' => $conditions,
   'fields' => $fields)
);
$values = array_values($results);
list($node) = $values;

echo '<pre>'; 
debug($fields);
debug($conditions); 
debug($results);
debug($values); 
debug($node); 
exit;
```

Now you can see which variable is passed as undefined.